# Does Oracle JDK's ZipFileSystem support ZIP64?

Tags: java, zip, nio

We hit a strange exception 'java.util.zip ZipException: loc: wrong sig -> 72ce7495' when unzipping a huge zip file (bigger than 4G) with following codes:

```
final URI jobFileSystem = URI.create("jar:" + file.toUri().toString());
try (final FileSystem resFileSystem = FileSystems.newFileSystem(jobFileSystem, ImmutableMap.of());
            final Stream<Path> zipEntryFilePaths = Files.walk(resFileSystem.getPath("/"))) {

        return zipEntryFilePaths
                .parallel()
                .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                .map(zipEntryFilePath -> {
            final String zipEntryFileName = getEntryFileName(zipEntryFilePath);
            try {
                final Path targetFilePath = targetFolder.resolve(zipEntryFileName);

                // Code for extracting zipEntryFilePath to targetFilePath
                // ...
                // ....

                return packageFilePath;
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                throw new UncheckedIOException(ioe);
            }
        }).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

The huge zip file was created with zip command on a linux machine. The zip command was compiled with ZIP64_SUPPORT option.

```
Copyright (c) 1990-2008 Info-ZIP - Type 'zip "-L"' for software license.
This is Zip 3.0 (July 5th 2008), by Info-ZIP.
Currently maintained by E. Gordon.  Please send bug reports to
the authors using the web page at www.info-zip.org; see README for details.

Latest sources and executables are at ftp://ftp.info-zip.org/pub/infozip,
as of above date; see http://www.info-zip.org/ for other sites.

Compiled with gcc 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16) for Unix (Linux ELF) on     Nov 10 2015.

Zip special compilation options:
    USE_EF_UT_TIME       (store Universal Time)
    SYMLINK_SUPPORT      (symbolic links supported)
    LARGE_FILE_SUPPORT   (can read and write large files on file system)
    ZIP64_SUPPORT        (use Zip64 to store large files in archives)
    UNICODE_SUPPORT      (store and read UTF-8 Unicode paths)
    STORE_UNIX_UIDs_GIDs (store UID/GID sizes/values using new extra field)
    UIDGID_NOT_16BIT     (old Unix 16-bit UID/GID extra field not used)
    [encryption, version 2.91 of 05 Jan 2007] (modified for Zip 3)

Encryption notice:
    The encryption code of this program is not copyrighted and is
    put in the public domain.  It was originally written in Europe
    and, to the best of our knowledge, can be freely distributed
    in both source and object forms from any country, including
    the USA under License Exception TSU of the U.S. Export
    Administration Regulations (section 740.13(e)) of 6 June 2002.

Zip environment options:
         ZIP:  [none]
      ZIPOPT:  [none]
```

Would there be any option we should provide to make the ZipFileSystem work properly with a zip file bigger than 4G? Many thanks for any help or hints.

Comment: According to [this post](https://blogs.oracle.com/xuemingshen/entry/zip64_support_for_4g_zipfile), ZIP64 support is added into the OpenJDK7 build(b55).

Comment: I faced the same issue with a zip fille zipped with the linux zip utility. After I change the zip with 7zip (added an empty file to completely update the zip) it was possible to use the 6,5GB zip without any problem

Comment: I am seeing this error in Java 8 too, and in my case too, the zip was created by infozip on Linux.

Comment: I am seeing this error with OpenJDK 11.0.4+11